# How do I remove the elements of one vector from another?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a double value, A, which is

```
[1,4,7,6]
```

I also have B, which is an array that contains many more values. I have a new variable, C, which is essentially a double value of all these numbers (all of them in one cell, vs. five).

```
[1,4,7,6]
[2,6,9,12]
[3,1,17,13]
[5,7,13,19]
[1,5,9,15]
```

How do I remove the elements (not the actual values) from C? I want to end up with this.

```
 [2,6,9,12,3,1,17,13,5,7,13,19,1,5,9,15]
```

How do I get this? I've used these commands:

```
C(A) = [];
```

and

```
C = C(setdiff(1:length(C),A));
```

The problem is that when I run that command, I get this instead of what I want.

```
[4,7,2,12,3,1,17,13,5,7,13,19,1,5,9,15]
```

Clearly that isn't the same as what I have. It's throwing off the rest of my results and I need to fix this specific issue.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

So I figured out that it's spewing the CORRECT numbers out, just in the wrong order. I have to sort it in order for it to work correctly. This is a problem because it causes the next command to be non-functional because the ismember command has issues with the removal (I don't know why, I'm still working on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Double array case

If `B` is a double array, you can use `setdiff` with `'rows'` and `'stable'` options, like so -

```
C = reshape(setdiff(B,A,'rows','stable').',1,[])
```

With `ismember`, you can perform the same operation, like so -

```
C = reshape(B(~ismember(B,A,'rows'),:).',1,[])
```

You can also use a `bsxfun` approach as suggested by @Amro -

```
C = reshape(B(~all(bsxfun(@eq, B, A),2),:).',1,[])
```

---

## Cell array case

If `B` is a cell array with number of elements in each cell equal to the number of elements in `A`, then you can firstly convert it to a double array - `B = vertcat(B{:})` and then use either of the above mentioned tools.

Or you can use a `cellfun` based approach that avoids conversion to a double array, like so -

```
excl_rows = B(~cellfun(@(x1,x2) isequal(x1,x2), B, repmat({A},size(B,1),1)),:)
C = horzcat(excl_rows{:})
```

Or another `cellfun` based approach that avoids `repmat` -

```
exclB = B(~cellfun(@(x1) isequal(x1,A), B),:)
C = horzcat(exclB{:})
```

## Example with explanation -

```
%// Inputs
A = [1,4,7,6]
B = {[1,4,7,6]
    [2,6,9,12]
    [3,1,17,13]
    [5,7,13,19]
    [1,5,9,15]}

%// Compare each cell of B with A for equality.
%// The output must be a binary array where one would be for cells that have 
%// elements same as A and zero otherwise.
ind = cellfun(@(x1) isequal(x1,A), B) 

%// Thus, ~ind would be a binary array where one would reperesent unequal 
%// cells that are to be selected in B for the final output.
exclB = B(~ind)

%// exclB is still a cell array with the cells that are different from A.
%// So, concatenate the elements from exclB into a vector as requested.
C = horzcat(exclB{:})
```

Output -

```
A =
     1     4     7     6
B = 
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
ind =
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
exclB = 
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
C =
     2     6     9    12     3     1    17    13     5     7    13    19     1     5     9    15
```

Comment: I already have a command that converts B into the C that I want though. Is that the only way for it to work?

Comment: @Ashwin Are you asking if there's any alterantive way, other than `setdiff` to get `C`? By the way isn't your `B` a 2D matrix or is it a cell array?

Comment: Another way to get row indices (assuming A and B are numeric matrices): `idx = all(bsxfun(@eq, B, A),2)`

Comment: B is a cell array that has multiple columns of data (I have a for loop that extracts it). A is just data FROM cell array B so it is a double.

Comment: @Amro Thank you, added your suggestion! :)

Comment: @Ashwin Just curious if it worked for you? If it did, consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark at the top-left corner of the solution right below the up/down arrows that are for up/down-voting, so that it could be considered here in Stackoverflow as a "closed" case.

Comment: I'll make sure to select your answer ;)

Comment: Okay so I figured out the problem with the current `C = B(setdiff(1:length(B),A));` - It's deleting the 1st, 4th, 7th, and 6th values. How can I get it to just delete a 1, 4, 7, and 6, without deleting ALL of the entries with those values?

Comment: @Ashwin What must be the expected output for this new case then?

Comment: @Divakar basically what I want is to just delete the NUMBERS 1, 4, 7, and 6. When I use setdiff, it deletes all of these numbers so that's not working for me at the moment. The expected output should be what's written in the OP. What I'm getting is that all 1's, 4's, 6's and 7's are getting deleted.

Comment: @Ashwin I don't think I understood you well enough there, but check out the added *Example*, it gives the expected output. Maybe the way you are inputting A and B is different?

Comment: @Divakar that example did help a lot. Can you explain how it works, since I have other sets of data like this that I have to run it through and it looks specialized just for this set of data.

Comment: @divakar yes they make sense but the first command, `ind = cellfun(@(x1) isequal(x1,A), B)` is confusing me. Can you explain what the x1, isequal, and the general syntax of the function mean? thanks :)

Comment: @Ashwin `@(x1) isequal(x1,A)` is an anonymous function with `A` as constant and `x1` as the parameter, which `cellfun`  uses for operating on each of its cells. The MATLAB documentation on these two is really comprehensive and can help you the most - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

Comment: I have more data. One of the sets of data is a control group, which is 100% identical to itself. The data is just

`A = {[1 2 3 4]
      [1 2 3 4]
      [1 2 3 4]
      [1 2 3 4]
      [1 2 3 4]`

For some reason when I do the function on it, exclB comes out as a 0x1 cell which doesn't work with the rest of the function. The data I put in the OP works but the rest of my data does not.

Comment: @Ashwin Use this for that case `ind = cellfun(@(x1,x2) isequal(x1,x2),A, B)` and rest stays the same. Now in this case, since no cell in A matches the corresponding one in B, all the elements in B would come in the output vector.

Comment: It is all in a large cell array that I pull columns from using a FOR loop. Since this is not the final data I have (the final data has hundreds of columns and there are no two cells that are exactly the same